# What is the recommended way to store StepCount in Parse Cloud or healthkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, healthkit

I've two approaches of which I don't know which one is best suitable for a scalable app or if there is a better way of doing this.

1) To store stepcount, distance  in Healthkit 
if Yes, then I am able to get data back if lost iPhone or buy new phonw using icloud ?

2) To store stepcount, distance  in ParseCloud ?
If yes, Right now My app do not have any login mechanism, then I have to implement that to extract data for each user separately ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HealthKit you won't know if permission to store the step count has been granted. Therefore you can't be sure that the data is saved AT ALL - regardless of whether they get a new phone.

I would use ParseCloud, and also attempt to store data in HealthKit as 'added value'.